# Having trouble loading text file from resources on linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to read a textfile that I have in my resources folder for testing. I have tried at least 3 different implementations that work properly on windows, but they all fail on linux.

Current project looks like

```
/src/test/java
  /com/my/app/util/Class_needs_text.java
/src/test/resources
  /com/my/app/util/text_file.txt
```

Class_needs_text.java

```
...
private static final String LOADTHIS = "/com/my/app/util/text_file.txt"; 
private static final String LOADTHAT = "text_file.txt"; 
// both of these work on windows, but not linux
java.net.URL url = Class_needs_text.class.getResource(LOADTHIS);
java.nio.file.Path resPath = java.nio.file.Paths.get(url.toURI());
fileContents = new String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(resPath), "UTF8");
```

I've checked linux and the text file is being copied to both the class folder directory on build. (./src/test/resources/com/my/app/util/text_file.txt to
./target/test-classes/com/my/app/util/text_file.txt)

Sorry if this was way too verbose. Cliffs: I need to read the contents of a resource folder located text file in both windows and linux.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If you are running the program from Eclipse, also make sure that /src/test/resources is set up as a source folder.

Comment: I'm running from Maven. I'll see if any of my maven setting are different windows vs linux.

Comment: See if you can read using Class_needs_text.classgetResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a getResource() is called on a class, the class will delegate that call to it's class loader, I'm not sure if there is a difference between unix and windows JVMs.  Shouldn't make difference on OS because, class loader that is loading class should have same visibility to the resource.

If you are trying to load a resource in a static method, you could try getting class loader.

```
Class_needs_text.class.getClassLoader().getResource(LOADTHIS);
```

If you are in a non-static method

```
this.getClass().getResource(LOADTHIS);
```

Comment: It is a static method. I tried this before. On windows this doesn't work for any of the following:/com/my/app/util/text_file.txt, text_file.txt, or /text_file.txt. Should I be using something else?